# Is it possible to share albums privately on Flickr?

Tags: flickr

I post my pics from various shoots and events on Flickr (portraits, family events, baby showers, etc.). I arrange my photos into Albums, e.g., all the shots from a reunion are in the "May Reunion" Album.

#### What I want to do

I want to send the link for the Album to a set email distribution list (e.g., all those who attended the reunion), so they can all view the pics on Flickr. I want the folks to be able to view the pics without having to do anything "extra" like creating a new account, creating a password, etc. I have been able to do this so far, and folks have viewed the pics for a certain Album.

#### The problem

When I send the link for the Album to the distribution list, the viewer goes directly to the Album I want them to view, but they also have ability to view all the other Albums that are on my Flickr page. I don't want them to view all my other Albums, only the Album I sent the link for.

I've tried different "privacy" settings and "guest passes", etc., that are outlined in the Flickr instructions, but my viewers inevitably come back and say they can't view the images for some reason. So, I've just resorted to keeping everything "public" without any restrictions just so everyone can view the Albums I send the link for.

All seems pretty straightforward, and the Flickr instructions seems to say I should I be able to do this rather easily. But I'm sorry to say I must be missing something on this one. Any Flickr experts out there that can help me determine what I'm doing wrong?

#### NET

I want to simply send an email to group of folks with a link to an "Album" of pics on my Flickr page. Want them to only view that Album - and not all my Albums. The group of folks changes, depending on the photoshoot. Also, don't want viewers to have to sign up for any type of new accounts, etc.

Comment: If all your pictures are public, then everyone can see all photos. You could create a new account for every album, that way it will be difficult to find the other pictures.

Comment: Or just create a separate account for just your family photos, if that is the only set of people you are concerned with.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's going wrong with the Guest passes? Ideally you would just set all photos to private and [give out guest passes](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/flickr/SLN13039.html?impressions=true).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to share only one album from Flickr?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/90195/is-it-possible-to-share-only-one-album-from-flickr)

Answer (score 10):

The problem appears to be that you are just copying the link to your album, which won't work if everything is marked private.  You have to send the email from the 'Share' icon located in the upper right when you are on your album home page - with this facility, you can either get Flickr to send the e-mail or just get the Guest Pass link yourself and copy and paste that into your e-mail. For your use case, the second option is probably easier.

This assumes of course that all your photos are marked private, which is what you need to prevent anyone else from looking at them.

Comment: I've once received a guest pass link through regular e-mail (non-Flickr) so I assume copy pasting the guest pass link works.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the suggestions, I was able to work through some options and I found my problem: I was emailing the link to the album (the thing like http://www.flickr.com/photos/*user name*/sets/*number*/) rather than the guest pass link (something like http://www.flickr.com/gp/*user name*/*some characters*/).

In any event, the corrected process for me is: 1) I have to set ALL the pics in ALL my Groups to Private (using the Group Batch edit feature). 2) Go to the Group that I want to give access to. 3) Click Share button 4) Click Guest Pass, and Private checkbox 5) Cut and Paste that URL in my email to the viewers. Email recipients will get the link and Flickr will open to only that Group and they will be able to view the pics in that Group indefinitely, or until I choose to "Expire" the Guest Pass via the Guest Pass history option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also to mention to have the Safety filter to Safe (not restricted) otherwise you cannot share.

Comment: @markthomas - This is pretty much the exact answer I gave you before you posted this, it would have been nice to have had my answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if Flickr had the option of showing just one album to select people without having to go through what seems to be the Supreme Court. 
I've found that if I click on one photo, the URL for *that* photo is shown. By sending that URL, the person you're privately sending it to can then click on the entire album. Back door, I know, but it works.