# Is it possible to share only one album from Flickr?

Tags: flickr

A few days back I made an account on Flickr. However, when I send an album link to some of my clients they are able to see my "my collection" and from there they can see my all albums. Is there a way to send an "only album link" to my clients so that they can't able to open any other albums?

Comment: Maybe ask flickr?

Comment: Verizon owns them now. No telling what will happen. I doubt Flickr knows what's going to happen to Flickr right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to share albums privately on Flickr?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/55956/is-it-possible-to-share-albums-privately-on-flickr)

Comment: Although the other question is older, I think this one is better written, as is the answer here compared to the older ones. I'm voting to close the older one as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @MichaelClark perhaps they should just be merged?

Comment: The problem with merging is the original question will be preserved and this one will be lost. All of the answers to both will appear to be answers to the poorly written original question.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly feasible with Flickr. What you need to do:

- Ensure all your photos are uploaded with a viewing privacy of "private"<sup>1</sup>. I suspect you've uploaded all your photos public.
- Put the photos you want to share in an album.
- From the album page, select "Share album" - you'll then get a link *with "gp" in it*. Send this link, not the regular album page link, to your client.<sup>2</sup>
- They will not be able to see any private photos which are *not* in that album.

Notes:

1. You could upload some with "friends" or "family" permissions. That's a complication which doesn't matter here - the point is they need to be not public, because that does what it says on the tin and lets anyone see them.
2. If you do send them the regular album page link (without "gp" in it), then they just won't be able to see anything at all because the photos are private.